# Java Regex :: first word in each line of a String

Tags: java, regex

Let's look at the following String:

```
String input = "A bla bla bla A blaa\r\n" +
               "B boo foo A B abo \r\n" + 
               "A yow B B yow";
```

And here is my regex:

```
String regex = "([AB]) (.*?)(?=$|[AB])";
```

I get with it each "A" or "B".

But what I look for is to get "A" or "B" only if it's the first word in each line of my String.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip : `^` matches the beginning of the line.

Comment: how about boundary matchers? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You should specify that the MULTILINE mode is required :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 2 things here:

- Enable [*MULTILINE*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) mode
- Use `^` to match the `AB` only at the beginning.

This regex would work:

```
"(?m)^[AB]"
```

Comment: Thank you again. It helped me. But can you explain me, what Multiline do exactly? I could'nt understand it from the Java docs.

Comment: @RohitJain Lol, I was getting confused =P

Comment: @yataodev MULTILINE allows you to perform match accors lines separated by `\n` or `\r\n`. In those cases, `^` and `$` don't match just the beginning and end of the entire string, but of every single string separated by `\n`. Other anchors `\A` and `\Z` take over the `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the entire string.

Comment: @Rohit Okay, I get it :) Thanks

Comment: @Rohit How can I combine MULTILINE with DOTALL? I want to get the third with the second line like this example:
    'String input = "A bla bla bla A blaa\r\n" +
                    "B boo foo A B abo \r\n" + 
                    "Kobe Bryant \r\n" +
                    "A yow B B yow";'

Comment: Use `(?ms)` instead of `(?m)`.

Comment: Here the complete regex:
`((?ms)^[AB]) (.*?)(?=$|[AB])`

Comment: @yataodev What output do you want?

Comment: `Group1: A <br/>  
Group2: A bla bla bla A blaa <br/>
G1: B <br/>
G2: boo foo A B abo <br/>
Kobe Bryant`
And so on

Comment: @Rohit: Have you any idea?

Comment: I get it finally!  
  The RegEx should be: `(?sm)(^[AB]) (.*?)(?=^[AB]|\\z)`

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:
  ([AB]).*

Match:
  1) A & A bla bla bla B blaa
  2) B & B boo foo A B ab
  3) A & A yow B B yow

Explain what you need. Look for results: http://fiddle.re/c1rwn

Comment: I don't think that that's what the OP is looking for.